# How do I create a palette file that I can use in Krita, in GIMP, from an image?

Tags: color, gimp

I want to use GIMP to create the palette automatically from a series of colors in squares that I have ready, but I can't find the option in this series of instructions:

> Import a New Palette
>
> The Import a New Palette dialog has a few controls, but these are straightforward. Firstly click the **Image radio button** and then the drop-down menu beside it to ensure that you have selected the image you wish to use. If you have made a selection to select just part of the image, click the Selected Pixels only tick box.

[image: Palette docker in GIMP]
            [image: example palette]

Comment: Hi watercollider, this is a very confusing question. It looks like you answered your own question. Could you maybe [edit] your question and tell us what exactly your issue is?

Comment: @PieBie Looks like OP found a text tutorial, but has troubles following the steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a record of the steps you already pointed out.

The mentioned *image radio button* is inside the *Import Palette...* dialog. It seems like you have not opened that dialog so far and therefore couldn't find the radio button.

[image: Steps]